Can the fundamental theorems of real analysis be proven/developed without proof by contradiction?
I've been reading about philosophical debates between mathematicians, and some seemed to reject the ideas of real analysis (such as the extreme value theorem) based on a school called "intuitionism", where they rejected things such as proof by contradiction.

What fundamental theorems are you referring to?

Short answer. Some things can be proved, some can't, depending on the particular fundamental axioms you choose.

Much of real analysis can be developed in “Constructive Analysis” but the formulations tend to be much less elegant.

The key ingredient in a proof by contradiction is the law of excluded middle (LEM).  Logics of intuitionstic type differ from classical logic in that they do not incorporate LEM.  There is a lot of work on re-doing classical analysis without reliance on LEM.  Perhaps the most famous book is the one by Errett Bishop:

Bishop, Errett. Foundations of constructive analysis. McGraw-Hill Book Co., New York-Toronto-London, 1967

(there is also a later edition published after Bishop's death, listing two authors: Bishop and Bridges).  The book was described as "the bible of the latter-day, secular, intuitionistic approach to mathematics" by Fred Richman in his MathSciNet review of the book.
However, reworking analysis without LEM turns out to be difficult.  Thus, certain key results cease to be true, such as the extreme value theorem.  Some of the philosophical and technical issues involved were analyzed in

Katz, K.; Katz, M. "Meaning in classical mathematics: Is it at odds with Intuitionism?" Intellectica 56 (2011), no. 2, 223-302. https://arxiv.org/abs/1110.5456 and https://www.persee.fr/doc/intel_0769-4113_2011_num_56_2_1154


I am looking forward to constructive criticism from the downvoter.
